# Not able to deploy large wlapp on IBM MobileFirstServer

Tags: deployment, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

I am not able to deploy 35MB Android wlapp on my IBM MobileFirst 7.1 server and got this message "The resource or service cannot be found. Try again later." but can deploy it if I have reduced its size. I am using Liberty profile.

Comment: Provide the messages.log file. Are you using MySQL as your database?

Comment: Thank you Idan. There is no errors or warnings in server messages.log file and I am using oracle database not mysql.

Comment: Please provide the messages.log file anyway.

Comment: attached the messages.log file url: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/f9b99638ab96e1a3ea9f414b10b386eb20151004081542/2a4157199c232a7946d98e2fea0bcfff20151004081542/198765

Comment: Try to add trace and provide the trace.log file after the error was encountered. Add the following to the server.xml file: `<logging traceSpecification="*=audit=enabled:com.worklight.*=info=enabled" />`. More trace options at the bottom of the page, here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_configure_logging_dev_server.html

Comment: Thank you Idan, I have found the problem it was that IIS will block any request over 30MB for some security reasons then by increasing this limit to be 50MB it is working now.

Comment: please write this as an Answer to the question. Do not leave questions unanswered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem it was that IIS will block any request over 30MB for some security reasons then by increasing this limit to be 50MB it is working now.